# Improving a MySQL INNER JOIN query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, inner-join

I have tables A and B in which A has a PRIMARY key on (X,Y) and an additional key on the column 'id'; B has a PRIMARY key on (X,Y,Z). X, Y, and Z are all the same type, for both tables; A.id is an integer.

I want to run the following query:

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM 
A INNER JOIN B 
USING (X,Y)
WHERE A.id = 1234
```

However, the EXPLAIN for this select indicates that while the primary key is used for A, it is not used for B and will search ~10M rows as a result.

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_key     | key     | key_len | ref          | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ALL    | PRIMARY          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL         | 10659636 |             | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id       | PRIMARY | 8       | db.A.X,db.A.Y|        1 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

How can I optimize this query to make use of the primary keys for both A and B?

Comment: Try a composite index on `B(x,y)`

Comment: @kordirko If the primary on B is `(X,Y,Z)` then braymp already has a composite index of `(X,Y)` as part of that primary key.

Comment: About what percentage of `A` rows have `id=1234`?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; the may be subtle thing (datatypes, Engines, etc) that are adding to the problem.

Comment: If your version has it, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: I actually found that the query didn't take as long as I had thought, so no further help needed.